# Running function with parameter and combining characters

Tags: function, visual-studio-code, parameters

Whenever I run a function on Visual Studio Code, it says 'Adam is not define'. How can I fix this, so it says "Hey Adam! This is my marinara sauce recipe!" Here is my code:

```
function marinaraSauce(cookName){
   console.log('Hey, ' + cookName + '!' + 'This is my marinara sauce recipe!');
console.log('-Heat a medium-large saucepan over medium heat.');
console.log('- Add 2 tspns of oil and 5 carlic cloves, cook until golden, about 2 minutes')
console.log(' - Add 1/4 cup water, 2 cans of crushed tomates, and salt and season with black pepper to taste.')
console.log(' - Cover the pot, bring to a boil, reduce the heat to medium low, and simmer until the sauce is heated, about 10 minutes')
console.log('- Stir in 1/4 cup roughly chopped fresh basil, salt and pepper as needed.')
}
marinaraSauce("Adam");
```

Comment: I tried re running this code in the same format as above with the quotes around Adam. And I am still getting a reference error saying Adam not defined.

Comment: I just solved the error by clicking run and debug